# What does "stir to cover" mean?

Tags: stir-fry

I don't really understand what the phrase "stir to cover and warm" means. Can someone shed some light?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cut off a little too much of the phrase; it's "*add sauce* and stir to cover and warm." You're stirring to cover the other ingredients with the sauce, and to warm the sauce.